# Is the definition of continuity of a sesquilinear form I've found in a book broken?

Tags: operator-theory, bilinear-form

Let

- $\mathbb K\in\{\mathbb C,\mathbb R\}$
- $H$ be a $\mathbb K$-Hilbert space
- $\mathcal D(\mathfrak a)$ be a subspace of $H$ and $\mathfrak a:\mathcal D(\mathfrak a)\times\mathcal D(\mathfrak a)\to\mathbb K$ be sesquilinear

In [Definition 1.4](https://books.google.com/books?id=eSZqJOaiRUwC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22analysis+of+heat+equations+on+domains%22+%22definition+1.4%22&source=bl&ots=BVhti20lgP&sig=kSwWiHoYMogPhXDJNIKiT3jMfPQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAy8SQs7jRAhXHtRQKHRRIAeQQ6AEIJzAB) of [*Analysis of Heat Equations on Domains*](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7904.html) the authors states that $\mathfrak a$ is called

- **accretive** $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$\Re\mathfrak a(u,u)\ge0\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in\mathcal D(\mathfrak a)\tag1$$
- **continuous** $:\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists M\ge0$ with $$|\mathfrak a(u,v)|\le M\|u\|_{\mathfrak a} \|v\|_{\mathfrak a}\;\;\;\text{for all }u,v\in\mathcal D(A)\tag2$$ where $$\|u\|_{\mathfrak a}:=\sqrt{\Re\mathfrak a(u,u)+\|u\|_H^2} \text{ for }u\in\mathcal D(\mathfrak a)$$

> Isn't this definition broken? Unless $$\Re\mathfrak a(u,u)+\|u\|_H^2\ge0 \tag3 \text{ for }u\in\mathcal D(\mathfrak a)\;,$$ $\|\cdot\|_{\mathfrak a}$ might take values in $\mathbb C$ in which case the real numbers on the left-hand side of $(2)$ are compared with complex numbers on the right-hand side.

Clearly, if $\mathfrak a$ is accretive, then the definition of continuity is well-posed.

Comment: Yes, if we take $\mathfrak{a}(u,v) = -2\langle u,v\rangle$, that definition has a problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there a consistent definition for sesquilinear forms which are not accretive?

Comment: Well, there's the standard definition of continuity. But if $\mathfrak{a}$ isn't defined on the whole space, one probably isn't so interested in continuity with respect to the subspace topology induced by $H\times H$. Perhaps using $\lvert \Re \mathfrak{a}(u,u)\rvert$ gives you something useful when $\mathfrak{a}$ isn't accretive.